# MySQL/PHP database value check not allowing for extra characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a username check in PHP, and whenever someone enters the value 'username2' when 'username' already exists, it returns that it is already taken.

```
    include 'connect.php';

$username = $_POST['r_username'];
$password = $_POST['r_password'];
$email = $_POST['r_email'];

$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'username' = '$username'";

if(mysql_query($qry) != ''){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('This username has already been taken!');
    window.location = 'register.php';
    </script>";
}else{...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Odd, it shouldn't do that. Can you show what `$qry` contains in such a case? Also, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: how long is username column in database?

Comment: Hello, [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: I know it's vulnerable, I have mysql_real_escape_string and addslashes for that. @ Dorward, seen the strip before but I love it still.

Answer (score 2):

`$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'username' = '$username'";`

I don't know much about php or MySql, but just wanted to ask if the field_name should be 'username' or without quotes. May be its taking it as value instead of column_name. I'm not sure

Comment: Right. He should use backticks instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query_response = mysql_query($qry)
if (mysql_num_rows($query_response) > 0) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('This username has already been taken!');
    window.location = 'register.php';
    </script>";
}
else {
echo 'This username has not been taken yet. Please, proceed';
}
```

Take a look what [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns. Your condition (`mysql_query($qry) != ''`) will always be `true`

Also, use backticks instead of apostrophes (') to enclose column names in queries. Now you comparing whatever $username string is with string `username`, but not a `username` column.

BTW, I agree with the others. Your query is not protected against SQL Injections. Use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
```

Comment: I entered a username with a number on the end and it worked great, but when I entered the exact same username (After verification that it was in the database), it didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `mysql_query()` incorrectly. It returns a resource to be used in other functions.

Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I've used it for tons of other fetches like the one above, and it works fine. What other method should I be using then?